# new line character in csv file spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to read a CSV file  with apache spark (version 3). I am facing two issues

1. One of the field in the csv file contains new line character because of which the row is getting split into two rows
2. One of the column contains(which contains new line character too) comma so the records gets split into multiple columns

Below is the code and the output I am getting

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("Sample App").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
        
        session.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");
        
        
        

        
        Dataset<Row> df = session.read().format("csv").
                option("quote","*" )
                .option("multiLine", "true")
                 .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
                 .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
                .load("/home/deepak/sample_dataset/*.csv");
        df.printSchema();
        df.show(false);
        
        session.stop();
        

    }

}



root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------+---------------+------+----------------------------+
|_c0                                         |_c1            |_c2   |_c3                         |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------+------+----------------------------+
|15169                                       |Sample data I  |RST1  |"*Insurance data conversion.|
|Sample (Sample/Sample)Sample Sample't Sample|Sample Box 9999|Sample|Sample 888888-7014*"        |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------+------+----------------------------+
```

Below is the input.It is one single line if we open with MS excel.

```
*15169*,Sample data I,RST1,"*Insurance data conversion.
Sample (Sample/Sample)Sample Sample't Sample, Sample Box 9999, Sample, Sample 888888-7014*"
```

I am not able to figure out how to make spark read as a one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify `quote` because your quote is the default character `"`.

```
Dataset<Row> df = session.read().format("csv")
                 .option("multiLine", "true")
                 .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
                 .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
                 .load("/home/deepak/sample_dataset/*.csv");

df.show()
+-------+-------------+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_c0    |_c1          |_c2 |_c3                                                                                                                   |
+-------+-------------+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|*15169*|Sample data I|RST1|*Insurance data conversion.
Sample (Sample/Sample)Sample Sample't Sample, Sample Box 9999, Sample, Sample 888888-7014*|
+-------+-------------+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```